# How to bind thousands of domain names to one web application?

Tags: iis, web-applications, bind, domain-name

The idea is to allow people to assign their own domain name to a profile on my web site,

One thing I could do is to bind each domain name to the web app in IIS, but this will be ugly as I may have many domains in that list, also I wonder if this can impact the performance for that web application if I had so many domains associated with one web app,

Also, I like to make these changes programmatically instead of adding it manually (like when binding a domain name to a web app in IIS)

**Any ideas how to approach this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try the below power shell script for that. Make a csv file(name : Site.csv) having your domains in a column(Header name: name) and keep it in C Colon.

```
    $csv = import-csv C:\site.csv
    foreach($line in $csv)
    {
    $name = $line.name
    New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IPAddress "*" -Port 80 -HostHeader $name
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of New-WebBinding, I'm assuming that it will add the new entries to IIS (to the IIS XML file), so I wonder if the web application can slow down when having let's say 2000 domain name entries...